# How to reset back onItemClickListener to true after been set to null?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, onitemclicklistener

I have set onItemClickListener in my list view,items including videos, images and text. When user tap on the video in list view it plays fine. Now inside the method of  playVideo() I set the listview to **null** so as the user should not interact with the video while playing.

I want to **regain/rese**t back the **onitemClicklisterner** to **true** after the video finishes to play. How do I implement this, Kindly assist.

```
    private void playVideo() {

    listOfMessages.setOnItemClickListener(null);

    videoText.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(chattVideo));
    frameText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    videoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   try {
        videoText.setMediaController(mediaControllerText);
        mediaControllerText.show();
       videoText.seekTo(1);
      videoText.pause();
       videoText.stopPlayback();
       videoText.seekTo(1);
       videoText.resume();
    progressBarMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoText.start();

        videoText.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.start();

                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                        progressBarMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        videoText.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {


               listOfMessages.setOnItemClickListener(this);// if I do like this android studio complains it cannot be applied inside MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
                btnText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

        videoText.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                FancyToast.makeText(getContext(),"Something went wrong!",FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        FancyToast.ERROR,R.drawable.wheel,false).show();

                return false;
            }
        });


   } catch (Exception e) {
       PBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        FancyToast.makeText(getContext(),e.getMessage(),
                FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.WARNING,R.drawable.wheel,false).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method as below to do required stuff

Here is pseudo code

```
private void setListener(boolean isPlaying){
        if(isPlaying){
            your_listview.setOnItemClickListener(null);
        }
        else{
            your_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //YOUR CODE
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Now,simply call `setListener(true)` when video plays or else
  `setListener(false)`

Comment: @gabrielassenga Gald it helped. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I would use a boolean that you can set to true/false when the video is playing and depending on it's state the onClickListener can react differently.

**Edit**:

Or use `button.setClickable(false);` (has to be used after `.setOnClickListener()`.

Or `button.setEnabled(false);` (this one can even be used before `.setOnClickListener()`.

These two methods have the advantage that button animations get disabled too and they might work better if you have multiple clickable objects stacked on top of each other.
They are in the View class and can be called on a ListView too (but i didn't try that "live").

```
boolean isPlaying = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isPlaying){
                //do stuff
            } else {
                //do someting else
            }
        }
    });
}
```